# How to compare html checkbox values in php?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have three check box and three input field  something like this,

```
        <input type="checkbox" name="fruit" value="orange" >
        <input type="text" name="orange" >Orange
        <input type="checkbox" name="fruit" value="apple" >
        <input type="text" name="n" >Apple<br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="fruit" value="mango" >
        <input type="text" name="mango" >Mango
```

I have a mysql table named fruits with four column  named id, apple, orange, mango.
I want to do something like if user select orange , apple , mango (checkboxes)  I want to insert data into orange , apple , mango in the table from the three input field , or if user select two user check box  it will just insert data into two columns from the input field's value, or if just one check box is selected then insert into one column! what is the standard procedure to do that? Thanks in advance

Comment: Use conditional statements. http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php

Comment: how  if (isset($_POST['fruit'])) {}

Comment: how will get the three check box value then ! it's not simple if else condition ! don't try to be too smart !! stupid!

Comment: That's the general idea. Checkboxes, well you can use a `foreach` and implode.

Comment: You have an answer below.

Comment: why didn't you try to say it first ! Or is it forbidden to ask basic question. BTW I know php better than html thats why I stuck here. I spend a few hours to make it works and another few hours I searched it on google before posting it ! I didn't find something that gives me idea. If you can show me anything about this, any article or tutorial I'll apologize or you should apologize to me.

Comment: Say what first? Make what work? You included a form, nothing else. This is too broad AND unclear what you're asking. *"or you should apologize to me"* - you're not serious, ME? Apologize? for what? Get real. *Wow*

Comment: By the way, you need to treat your checkboxes as an array.

Answer (score 2):

Only checked checkboxes are sent, so use `isset`:

```
if (isset($_POST['mango']) || isset($_POST['apple']) || isset($_POST['orange'])) {
    $query = 'INSERT INTO table VALUES (orange, apple, mango) VALUES (';
    $query .= (isset($_POST['orange']) ? 1 : '') . ',';
    $query .= (isset($_POST['apple'])  ? 1 : '') . ',';
    $query .= (isset($_POST['mango'])  ? 1 : ''); 
    $query .= ')';
}
```

Comment: *Hm...* After the way I got grilled by the OP, I wish you all the best Panther ;-)

Comment: there are some errors in your code , I fixed it but not working the way it supposed  to!

Comment: @monir009: what errors you mean? What my code do and what should it do?

Comment: well its basic syntax error though :  syntax error, unexpected ')' you haven't close parenthesis properly in few lines like so   isset($_POST['orange']) ? 1 : '' . ',';

Comment: and wrote values twice :)

Comment: @monir009: if it writes values twice, you have somewhere error. Not in these 6 lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me.

My Code:

HTML

```
 <form  action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="POST">
<input type="checkbox" name="fruit[]" value="orange" >Orange
<input type="checkbox" name="fruit[]" value="apple" >Apple
<input type="checkbox" name="fruit[]" value="mango" >Mango
<input type="submit" value="Insert into Database">
</form>
```

PHP

```
 <?php 

// define variables and set to empty values
 $fruits = array();
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") 
{
  $fruits = test_input($_POST);
}
function test_input($data) 
 {
    $servername = "";// localhost, server name
    $username = "";// username
    $password = "";//password
    $dbname = "";//database name

   // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    for($i =0; $i < sizeof($data["fruit"]);  $i++)
    {
        //select query where count > 0 and fruitname = $data["fruit"]
        //If its first time, Select query returns false
        // write Insert into db table values(fruitname = $data["fruit"] , count =1)

    // if its exist value, select query returns count value,
    // update query set value = value+ 1 where   fruitname = $data["fruit"]
   }
}

?>
```

Comment: Try this code, give your database query and execute the query, If you using any other database and want how to write query  Follow this links,  [Select last id](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert_lastid.asp)